# undefined symbol for architecture

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, xcode4

How do I resolve the following:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKObjectLoaderTTModel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MyGroupViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The code that I have is:

```
- (void)createModel {
    RKObjectLoader* objectLoader = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/groups.json" delegate:nil];
    self.model = [RKObjectLoaderTTModel modelWithObjectLoader:objectLoader];
    [super createModel];
}


- (void)didLoadModel:(BOOL)firstTime {
    [super didLoadModel:firstTime];

    if ([self.model isKindOfClass:[RKObjectLoaderTTModel class]]) {
        RKObjectLoaderTTModel* model = (RKObjectLoaderTTModel*) self.model;
        NSMutableArray* items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[model.objects count]];

        TTListDataSource *dataSource = [[[TTListDataSource alloc] init] autorelease];

        for (Group* group in model.objects) {
            NSString* imageURL = group.creator.url;
            TTTableImageItem* avatar = [TTTableImageItem itemWithText:@" "
                                                             imageURL:imageURL];

            TTTableItem *item = 
            [TTTableSubtitleItem 
             itemWithText:group.name
             subtitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ members %@ topics ", group.members_count , group.topics_count]
             URL:@""];

            [items addObject:item];
            [items addObject:avatar];
        }

        dataSource.items = items;
        //dataSource.model = model;
        self.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Is the RKObjectLoaderTTModel class part of a library which you use?

Comment: yes it is...can this be an error on the header search path?

Comment: No, this means that the header can be found (this is why it compiles) but the library itself is not linked.

Comment: oh that's true...the library is not linked

Comment: See the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the target settings of Xcode under "Build Phases" is a part "Link binary with Libraries" make sure your library is listed there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing one of the Framework which "RKObjectLoaderTTModel" using. Look in to this viewController and add missing framework and I think it will solved your problem.

This is is just my thought from above error. Hope this help.

Comment: you mean add the missing imports that RKObjectLoaderTTModel is using?

Comment: No, I meant framework. for example coreLocation, MessagUI etc.